# PHP Get string after a specific regex pattern match

Tags: php, regex, string, email, imap

I am using the regex pattern from this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416262/

In the email's body message, there can be multiple emails so I am wanting to grab the email after a specific string:

```
The following users in your Google Apps domain appear to be affected: name@domain.com ....
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
$message = (imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2)); 
if($message == '')
{
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);
}
// Text inside pattern can be made smaller too (i.e. from 'Google' to 'affected:')
$pattern = '/(?<=The following users in your Google Apps domain appear to be affected: )\S+/i';
preg_match($pattern, $message, $match);
```

When I get the output of $message and check the pattern on this website: http://www.phpliveregex.com/ It works (shows the email), but it does not work in my code.

var_dump($match) shows

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

I'd like to grab just the email in the body and use it later.

**Edit #1:**

```
if (preg_match('/affected:/',$message)
    echo 'true';
```

returns true, but it does not if it is '/affected: /' (with space). The gettype of $message is a string, but I am wondering if there's are new line characters too. Here is the real email view:
[**Real email sample**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VwTf.png)

**Edit #2:**
Sorry for misleading/not providing the real information (my first time working with imap). The issue was the newline characters that were added. I ended up replacing all newline instances with ' '. Now,

```
if (preg_match('/The following users in your Google Apps domain appear to be affected: /',$string))
    echo 'true';
```

returns true, but my bigger regex still returns var_dump as empty.

**Edit #3:**
With a little testing, I had to add a few more spaces at the end to make it go from "affected: " to "affected:     ". If you can help make the regex a little cleaner, please do so.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Can you verify the contents of `$message` (`print_r($message)`)?

Comment: I am able to echo/print_r contents of $message, and the specific string and email exists (along with a bunch of other text)

Comment: I'm getting an empty array on phpliveregex. Can you provide a link of when it is working there? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bH4

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a space in the OP (not my actual code): http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bH5

Comment: Code works, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e38aeb2f6fdcc3696f0311df64d1ccf962fec7d, so `$message` must not be what is being shown here... or are you trying to access the first key of this index? The first key won't be populated because you aren't capturing anything.

Comment: If I set $message to the exact string (The following user...), then it works. But if i set $message to the result of imap_fetchbody, I get var_dump as empty. So the problem is with the return of imap_fetchbody.