# PHP preg_match Wildcard pattern search

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, wildcard

This is an extension of my previous SO question: [PHP Get string after a specific regex pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057201)

Currently I am using this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=The following users in your Google Apps domain appear to be affected: )\S+/i';
```

I would like to be able to use something like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=The following * affected: )\S+/i';
```

To get the same result by using:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $eBody, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0] . "# <br>";
}
```

Comment: I think  you want `.*` after `following`, not just `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`\K`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k) escape sequence to manipulate variable-length look-behind:

```
$pattern = '/The following.*?affected: \K\S+/i';
```

Comment: Thank you to you and anubhava! He was a few seconds early, but your response shows up on top and it is a little more "complete".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\K` (match reset):

```
/The following .*? affected: \K\S+/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6fY3/10)